# French expressions meaning "older" as used in translations of Kafka's Amerika

Tags: sens, traduction, allemand

This question is on how a sentence from Kafka's *Amerika* (*Der Verschollene* or *Le Disparu*) was translated into French.  It is from the chapter titled 'Weg Nach Ramses' ('Sur la route de Ramsès' or 'La Marche vers Ramsès').

> Da sah er ein paar Schritte vor sich eine **ältere**, offenbar zum Hotelpersonal gehörige Frau, die lachend mit einem Gaste redete.

Into English it has been translated as follows by Willa and Edwin Muir:

> Then a few steps in front of him he saw an **elderly** woman who clearly belonged to the hotel staff and was talking and laughing with a customer.

In a later translation, by Mark Harman, it goes:

> Then a few steps in front of him he saw an **older** woman, who clearly belonged to the hotel staff, talking and laughing with a guest.

I have also two French translations.  The one by Alexandre Vialatte from 1946 gives:

> Il aperçut alors à quelques pas de lui une femme **d’un certain âge** qui faisait certainement partie du personnel et riait avec un client.

Bernard Lortholary's, from 1988, gives:

> C’est alors qu’il vit à quelques pas de lui une femme **plus très jeune** qui faisait manifestement partie du personnel de l’hôtel et qui parlait en riant avec un client.

**QUESTION**

1. How can *d’un certain âge* mean *ältere* or *older* or *elderly* (ignoring the differences between these themselves).
2. How can *plus très jeune* mean *ältere*?  Does it need a *ne* before *plus*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other options like "vieille" or "agée" are way too direct, and not polite towards the elderly woman.

1. "D'un certain âge" is an euphemism for "pretty old". Wordreference gives "of a certain age" as a translation for exactly that. It's a number we don't exactly know but it's not a small number.
2. We don't need "ne" as there is no verb. If you say "une femme plus très jeune" you don't use it, but you can change the sentence a little to fit it in: "une femme qui n'était plus très jeune..."
   I think you can see how "not so young" can express being old in a polite way.

Comment: Thanks for directly answering the point about *plus* not needing *ne*. I guess *plus* is like *personne* in having a built-in negation that comes out in the right context.

Answer (score 5):

The important factor behind these expressions is the social unacceptability of referring to an old person as just being *old*, and therefore the search for roundabout ways of expressing the age of the person. This is already present in the original — *ältere* instead of *alte* – as well as in the English translations — *older* and *elderly* instead of *old*.

*D'un certain âge* and *plus très jeune* are two such expressions which rely on conveying meaning by way of a **sous-entendu**, i.e. a second, real meaning "underlying" the literal meaning.

- *une femme d'un certain âge* here means "a woman of *some* years": meaning her age is not known, but it's a somewhat non-negligible quantity. The underlying meaning is *old*, and is in the same register as English *an older woman*.
- *plus très jeune* is a [litote](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litote) which aims to emphasize the age of the person by negating its opposite. To me, this actually sounds harsher than *older*, though still not as harsh as *vieille femme*.

Note that the literal translation "une femme plus vieille"* does not have the same meaning. It implies a comparison to another (specific) person, which isn't the case here.

Another term that could have been used here is *une femme âgée* (which means *an elderly woman*, not *an aged woman*).

Answer (score 4):

*Un certain âge* is a polite way of saying old, or at least not young. *Certain* here means a certain amount, as in not insignificant. It also adds, funny enough, a modicum of uncertainty. We're not sure how old exactly this person is, but not young anyway.

*Plus très jeune* is to be taken as a one-word expression, if you will, not a grammatical construct. You can and should say Cette personne n'est plus très jeune. But you'll say *plus très jeune, pas très vieux,* etc...