# Lire l'arithmétique: multiplications dont le premier terme est 0 ou 1

Tags: usage, mathématiques

Je sais que les mathématiques possèdent une langue un peu à côté de la langue habituelle, qu'elles utilisent parfois des définitions très pointues à l'exclusion d'autres acceptions parfaitement correctes, ou qu'elles étendent parfois certains concepts par-delà l'entendement habituel.

> La multiplication est un exemple des deux cas:
>
> - *« Multiplier les démarches »* n'est pas une opération mathématique, les démarches n'engendrent pas de démarches et l'accumulation en ce cas tiendrait de toute manière davantage de l'addition que de la multiplication. Mais la langue courante n'additionne pas les démarches, elle les multiplie.
> - *« La nuit venue, le spectacle terminé, la foule s'est multipliée »* est pour le moins surprenant. Le mathématicien pourra néanmoins affirmer qu'une multiplication par un dixième, ou même un centième, c'est encore une multiplication.

Mais déjà à des niveaux beaucoup plus élémentaires, on peut déjà se poser des questions. Ainsi, en arithmétique, comment doit-on prononcer des expressions comme « 1×0 », « 1×1 », « 1×2 », « 0×3 » en utilisant le mot **fois** ? Ce mot est-il à être considéré comme féminin ? Ou comme un simple opérateur séparé des termes de l’opération qu’il définit ?

- **1×0:** *« Une fois zéro », « un fois zéro » ou peu importe ?*
- **1×1:** *« Une fois un », « un fois un »? Je suppose qu’on ne dira guère « une fois une », et encore moins « un fois une ».*
- **1×2:** *« Une fois deux », « Un fois deux »?*
- **0×3:** *Peut-on dire « aucune fois trois »?*

Et le discours normal possède-t-il les mêmes normes qu'un discours technique, ou en quoi diffèrent-elles ?

---

**Clarification après soumission d’une réponse de ma part**

J'ai offert une réflexion sous forme de réponse ci-dessous. Son ton en est peut-être un peu désabusé, mais je ne désire pas qu’on l’interprète comme un abandon de ma part. J’ai rapporté, puis commenté, des propos qui me furent tenus et qui ont élargi considérablement ma vision du problème, mais sans vraiment apporter de solution définitive.

Voici ce qui au départ m’a incité à poser cette question : il y a quelques années, j’ai codé un petit programme informatique qui générait des questions arithmétiques, puis avais enregistré ma voix pour un volet oral du programme. J’avais alors opté pour le modèle *« une fois un »*, et jugeant que la chose n’était pas d’une importance capitale, j’en étais resté là. La curiosité m’a repris depuis, mais la littérature à ce sujet semble rare.

Comment: Cher dda, J'ai vu votre proposition d'édition, et bien que je crois en effet que la portion en gras (la liste détaillée) en sera plus lisible et je retirerai même complètement les guillemets. Je laisserai le reste tel quel à cause de l'absence d'espace insécable dans ce site (je le sais pour l'avoir essayé). Je préfère une petite entorse à l'usage qu'une ponctuation rejetée en début de ligne. Merci néanmoins.

Comment: Pour introduire une espace insécable, il faut saisir : `&nbsp;`

Comment: Ça allourdit bougrement la saisie, mais si ça plaît davantage...

Comment: @Toto  Ctrl + Maj + Espace c'est plus vite fait... (je pense que ça marche sous tous les systèmes...)

Comment: Canadian Multilingual Keyboard sur Windows, Alt+Epace, ne marchait pas pour moi. Ça créait bien une espace, mais elle n'était pas insécable sur ce site en particulier. Et comme je n'aime pas les deux-points ou les guillemets en début de ligne, je m'étais abstenu depuis.

Comment: @Laure: Merci pour l'information. Mais j'ai l'impression que cela ne fonctionne pas chez moi. (Windows 10).

Comment: En général j'ai opté pour le [copy-pasta](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/browsertest.htm) UTF-8 de l'insécable fine. Ça vaut ce que ça vaut.

Answer (score 4):

J’ai interrogé la mère de mes enfants à ce propos et je fais ici un résumé de ce qu’elle en a dit sans connaître la raison spécifique de mes questions.

**Première situation: les leçons des enfants (1 × qqch)**

Lorsque confrontée à l’écriture *« 1×qqch »*, elle dit spontanément *« un fois x »* à cause de l’écriture mathématique (c’est-à-dire parce qu’elle voit le symbole « 1 »). Nous avons donc *« un fois un »*, *« un fois deux »*, etc.

**Seconde situation: des recettes (1 × & 0 × qqch)**

Lorsque les quantités doivent être multipliées (il y a là une véritable opération mathématique de multiplication, je supposerai ici qu’elle double la recette), si la quantité est 1 (une cuillère à thé, une tasse, mais elle m’a confirmé que la valeur masculine imaginaire *un verre* subirait le même traitement), elle dira « une fois deux », parce que *fois* est féminin.

> *(Je note ici que ma propre version de la chose eût davantage été « deux fois une cuillère à thé » que « une fois deux », mais j’ai décidé de laisser parler quelqu’un d’autre que moi et mon opinion ne devrait pas interférer ici avec l’opinion que je présente).*

Je lui ai ensuite proposé la situation où la recette originale suppose une cuillère à thé de cannelle, mais qu’elle désire laisser de côté cet ingrédient. Après discussion au cours de laquelle elle m’arguait qu’elle dirait simplement *« Pas de cannelle »*, elle a fini par concéder qu’elle pourrait à la limite concevoir, pour rigoler, *« Aucune fois deux »* ou *« Rien fois deux »*.

*« Zéro fois deux »* ne faisait cependant pas partie des possibilités qu’elle considéra comme plausibles pour elle, preuve s’il en est besoin que la notion de zéro (le symbole et la valeur mathématique) peut demeurer très abstraite dans l’esprit des gens, qui lui préfèrent des concepts tels que « rien » ou « aucun », plus intuitifs.

**Troisième situation: 0 × qqch**

Mon amoureuse m’a dit que lors des leçons des enfants, elle demande *« zéro fois x »*, encore une fois à cause du symbole mathématique (0). Mais elle m’a alors mentionné que la transition de l’addition à la multiplication fut difficile pour elle quand elle était petite *(zéro plus sept égalant sept, il semblait naturel que zéro fois sept égale aussi sept)*, et qu’elle croyait que l’utilisation de concepts linguistiques bien assimilés comme *« rien »* ou *« aucun »* lui eût probablement facilité la tâche d’abstraction à l’époque *(je lui avais déjà suggéré ce type de lecture au cours de notre discussion sur la cannelle)*. Donc, quoiqu’elle n’ait jamais pensé auparavant à utiliser *« aucune fois huit »* ou *« cinq fois rien »* (mais *« trois fois rien »*, bien entendu, lui était connu :), elle a déclaré que ce serait une manière beaucoup plus facile de faire comprendre instinctivement la multiplication par zéro aux enfants. Pour justifier son opinion, elle a même soulevé deux points auxquels je n’avais pas songé:

- Le zéro, en plus d’être le symbole du rien du tout, contribue à l’augmentation des nombres qui se trouvent à sa gauche. Les expressions communes qui qualifient les gros montants d’argent comme étant des montants « avec beaucoup de zéros » sont pour le moins paradoxales quand on ne considère que la valeur nulle de l’entité mathématique. Le fait que ces zéros servent à noter la position et la puissance du chiffre non-nul à leur gauche donne en fait virtuellement beaucoup de valeur au symbole 0.
- Par ailleurs, le mot *« zéro »* est assez rare dans le discours quotidien. En effet, pour marquer l’absence, on utilise davantage des mots comme *« rien »*, *« aucun »*, *« vide »*, *[« plus de /ply.də/ »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25352/plus-sans-ne)* voire *« néant »*, que le quantitatif *« zéro »*. Zéro apparaît donc dans l’intellect des enfants beaucoup plus comme une notion mathématique à usage limité aux cours d’arithmétique que comme une représentation habituelle de l’absence. D’où les possibles difficultés d’assimiler zéro à rien quand il faut l’écrire et apprendre à le lire. Zéro est vraiment quelque chose (son symbole) et sa domestication ne passe même pas par la lecture des lettres qui le composent (comme un mot ordinaire). *« Zéro fois quelque chose »* arrive probablement plus comme *« quelque chose fois quelque chose »* que comme *« rien fois quelque chose »* dans la tête de l’enfant, d’où un inutile obstacle à la compréhension.

**En guise de conclusion (temporaire)**

Ma vision de la chose a été rudement mise à l’épreuve au cours d’une simple discussion avec la personne qui m’est la plus proche au monde. Je croyais avoir une question à deux choix de réponse et j’ai été confronté à de nombreux arguments et situations, générant des réponses multiples et variables. Je n’ose désormais plus imaginer combien de réponses et d’exceptions surgiraient de discussions prolongées. Mais je demeure curieux d’explorer ces possibilités...

Entretemps, il me semble soudainement que les grammaires sont d’un secours limité quand le but est d’introduire un concept mathématique utile dans l’entendement des enfants. La meilleure méthode sera celle qui parviendra à leur apprendre les lois du calcul, pas celles qui leur apprendra à énoncer comme il faut des résultats approximatifs ou faux. Par ailleurs, les gens semblent ne pas aimer beaucoup les maths, mais néanmoins fonctionner correctement avec le bagage qu’ils en ont, quoique de façon assez autonome, presqu’en circuit fermé.

Mais après tout, si quelqu’un fonctionne mieux avec ses trucs et raccourcis personnels qu’avec le canon de l’éducation, ainsi soit-il. Peut-être que ma question était inutile, en ceci que le résultat de calculs est plus important que la manière de les prononcer, et que si quelqu’un parvient toujours aux bons résultats, alors à quoi sert de lui reprocher d’y arriver par des sentiers exotiques. Nombre de calculateurs prodiges furent des pâtres qui passèrent des années à jouer avec les chiffres en gardant des moutons. Leurs méthodes, pour peu orthodoxes qu’elles furent sans doute, portèrent néanmoins de beaux fruits.

Comment: I've never yet read anything so charming on an SE site. Daily life always passes into grammatical abstractions with such wonderful difficulty, doesn't it?

Comment: Your comment really touched me! Thanks Luke!

Answer (score 2):

L'usage est le même pour les quatre exemples:

1×0: « **Une fois** zéro » ou « **un multiplié par** zéro », plus rarement « **un fois** zéro ».
1×1: « Une fois un » ou « un multiplié par un », plus rarement « un fois un ».
1×2: « Une fois deux » ou « un multiplié par deux », plus rarement « un fois deux ».
0×3: « **Zéro fois** trois » ou « **zéro multiplié par** trois ».

Je n'ai jamais entendu « aucune fois trois » mais ce n'est probablement pas grammaticalement incorrect.

« **Fois** » ayant toujours été en français un substantif féminin comme son ancêtre latin *[vicis](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vicis)*, je pense qu'il vaut mieux éviter « <s>un fois</s> x » que l'on [rencontre parfois à l'écrit](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un%20fois%20un%2C%20une%20fois%20un&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cun%20fois%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20fois%20un%3B%2Cc0) et plus souvent à l'oral, en particulier lors de la récitation de tables de multiplication.

Cet avis n'est pas contredit par les quelques vidéos que j'ai pu trouver sur You Tube où la table de un était récitée. Elles utilisent **toutes** la forme « **une fois** x » :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwJVAdKyFEE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgPexVGG2mA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDQRwypWqeo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0F1vFk5YC7E

La forme « x <s>fois une</s> » est incorrecte et inusitée (sauf constructions où *fois* ne s'applique pas à *une*, étant séparé par une virgule, par exemple : « Il était une fois, une marchande de foie, qui vendait du foie, dans la ville de Foix… »)

Comment: "Il vaut mieux éviter « un fois x »": pourquoi?

Comment: @Frank Parce que « [fois](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fois) » est un substantif féminin.

Comment: @Frank et que les déterminants numéraux cardinaux ne s'accordent pas **sauf** un, vingt et mille. « 21 secondes » se lit « vingt-et-**une** secondes ».

Comment: Il y a tout de même [une fois une](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un+fois+un%2Cune+fois+un%2C+une+fois+une&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cun%20fois%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20fois%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20fois%20une%3B%2Cc0). En observant les attestations, on se rend cependant compte que l'on est souvent loin de l'arithmétique *(«Il était **une fois un** bûcheron»/«Il était **une fois une** princesse...»)*

Comment: Je ne suis pas certain de la valeur de la référence, mais [voici un endroit](http://ekladata.com/zXtuywDw6jvLFYroKeFq5jjNkiQ.pdf) où l'on distingue la lecture _(multiplié par)_ et le calcul (pour lequel _fois_ est présenté, à juste titre selon moi, comme plus facile).

Comment: @jlliagre - oui, mais _fois_ peut être vu comme le nom de l'opérateur de la multiplication, plutôt que comme une "fois". En tout cas, cela ne me choque pas du tout, et je crois que je l'utilise.

Comment: If the English analogy helps, "times" isn't a noun in these expressions even though it can obviously be analyzed as one in other contexts. (Besides the fact that "Five times one" sounds like it would mean "one one one one one" in that reading, the case of "One time**s** five" makes its status crystal clear.) Since the other operations are not nouns (six plus four, three minus one, ten modulo two) there's also good reason to expect that "times" migrated from its original grammatical status to one that functions like the others. I wouldn't be surprised if it had become adverbial in French too.

Comment: @Feelew Indeed... I noticed that every one of the results on the first pages for [une fois une](http://ow.ly/wrGJ30aTY39) and [une fois un](http://ow.ly/9x9U30aTY74) is as you described! Either "Il était une fois un(e) [noun]" or a sentence that ends at "fois"... (Anyone know of a good way to exclude sentence breaks in ngram searches?)

Comment: Yes, I did notice that commas and even full stops were sometimes right in the middle of the lookup phrase _(‘Ce n’est arrivé qu’une fois, une seule, je te le jure! se défendit le mari’)_. Any way to filter out fairy tales by removing _‘Il était’_ before the lookup, also?

Comment: @Frank C'est vrai, ça ne me choque pas non plus et il m'arrive aussi de ne pas utiliser le féminin. Je pense dire plus souvent « vingt et un fois deux » que « vingt et une fois deux ». Je pense néanmoins, même après avoir lu les avis divergents exprimés ici et malgré mon propre usage, qu'il vaut mieux éviter ce conflit de genres.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Note that unlike "time", *fois* spelling remains the same in the singular or plural form (*foi* = faith is unrelated.)

Comment: Indeed, which means we have to be agnostic on that count — just observing that in the parallel case it's invariable and only superficially looks like the noun of the same spelling. (Incidentally, a survey of how languages have chosen words for their mathematical operators would be a good linguistics/SE post... interesting that both English and French chose a noun for multiplication.)

Comment: J'accepte cette réponse, parce que bien que vous et moi n'approchions pas ce problème de la même manière, vous avez ultimement assez bien couvert les possibilités (vidéos à l'appui), et la conversation à plusieurs voix qui a suivi fut très instructive, offrant les tendances générales, une comparaison utile à l'anglais, des opinions que l'on ne respecte même pas toujours soi-même. Si quatre personnes intéressées argumentent ainsi, et puisque les grammaires sont elles-même assez silencieuses sur ce point, je crois que le léger flottement dans l'usage continuera encore un temps.