# Parsing "plus de retour en arrière possible"

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots

I'm having trouble understanding this phrase. I understand that *ne plus* means "no longer", but this phrase does not have *ne*, and *plus* is moved to the top. Also, *est* is missing from *est possible*. How can I parse this phrase?

> N’oublie pas : une fois la machine lancée, **plus de retour en arrière possible**.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike English where traditional grammar states a verb is mandatory to form a complete sentence, a verbless sentence is possible in French where it is called ***phrase nominale***.

The sentence means:

> Don't forget: once the engine is launched, no rollback [[is] possible].

It might have been rephrased:

> N’oublie pas : une fois la machine lancée, le retour en arrière est impossible.

***Retour en arrière*** is kind of a set expression here, like ***retour à zéro*** or even ***retour vers le futur***. Breaking it with *retour **possible** en arrière* would make the sentence less idiomatic.

Nobody would even say *Retour possible à zéro*.

While rarer, verbless constructions do actually exist in English, for example:

> [Once all rooms are occupied,] no vacancy!

or:

> Mission: impossible

Comment: English has shortened forms also. I am upvoting this.

Answer (score 3):

You have to take it as a shortened form for *il n'y a plus de retour en arrière possible*. Same as for instance in the very common *Pas de problème !*. You can drop the 'il n'y a" in this case to add a sense of abruptness to the negation:

> J'arrive à la gare: trop tard, plus de trains ! Je sors de la gare, je cherche un taxi: pas de taxi !

The "ne" falls along with the verb, but there will be no ambiguity, the negative form is obvious just from "pas" ou "plus". In spoken French, the "ne" is often dropped anyway: it is very common to hear:

> J'ai pas d'argent
>
> J'ai plus d'argent

One might argue that the 2nd example is then ambiguous, as it may mean either *I have more money*, or *I don't have any money left*. But *plus* is pronounced [plys] if if is the comparative for quantities, and [ply] if it is the negation for something that existed before. If you encounter this in written, it will be the context that will determine how "plus* should be understood.

As for *possible*, it is an adjective that qualifies the noun *retour*: *Possible* is placed here after the noun it qualifies. I guess that the puzzling thing here is that it is not placed directly after *retour*: *en arrière* is here "closely attached" to retour for its meaning, so it is ok to not separate them by an adjective. You could also say *plus de retour possible en arrière* - some speakers will possibly say it just sounds "better". If you leave out *en arrière*, and that you add a full verbal form again, maybe the sentnce will make more sense to you:

> Il n'y a plus de retour possible.

Comment: Concerning the ambiguity of *plus (no more)* and *plus (more of)*: https://french.stackexchange.com/a/275/13100 and https://french.stackexchange.com/a/25362/13100

Comment: Good explanation except I am not sure that possible qualifies retour. It is built on: être possible, and is not "un possible retour" or "un retour possible"" where possible is an adjective qualifying retour. Il y a un retour possible is "une locution impersonnelle ou proposition impersonnelle" (dummy subject).

Comment: @Lambie I believe Greg's explanation is the right one, but thanks for bringing this up: it had me thinking for a moment. In this case, it would have been used with “avoir” *(as when you mention* «il y **a** un retour possible»), not with “être”, as you initially stated in your comment.

Comment: @Feelew I became confused by your comment and my own, which was also confusing. I believe the sentence is the general structure: Il est possible d'avoir un retour, il n'est pas possible d'avoir un retour. That's clearer. Le retour en arrière n'est plus possible. :) None of those has possible as qualifying retour. In no case are the variants we are discussing with the  noun retour with the adjective possible as a qualifier. We agree on that right?